# How to build a form that contains items of a collection

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models: a `wishlist` model and a `wish` model. A `wishlist` is made of `n` `wish` (`wish` have a reference to his `wishlist)`. I would like update a `wishlist` with a form. Here is the form I'd like to have:

```
input:text wishlist.name
 for wish in wishlist:
  input:text wish.name
  input:number wish.price
```

I'm new to django and don't know how to build a form that handle two models.

```
# models.py
class WishList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date of creation')

class Wish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=24, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    wishlist = models.ForeignKey(WishList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Try this [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Thanks @N.HariHaraSudhan :) That was what i needed !